# Como alimentar um input com uma variável get em php

Tags: php, html

Ola a todos tudo bem espero que sim, estou com uma dúvida relativamente simples, o que estou querendo é utilizar um arquivo para fazer inserção e também alteração em php referente a inserção está traquilo, bom o que eu gostaria seria atribuir os valores que eu passo via `$_GET['']` para o formulário assim o mesmo mostrar os valores que já fiz o select que estão em minha url para conseguir fazer a alteração de fato do id passado.

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="nome">
```

alguém já passou por isso, HELP.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido problema simples.

```
<?php $nome = (!empty($_GET['nome']) ? $_GET['nome'] : ''); ?>
<input class="input" type="text" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" name="nome">
```

Obrigado.

Comment: no caso do '''$nome''' antes de colocar ele nesse ponto faço uma atribuição de valor para não ficar uma variável indefinida.

Comment: Como faço uma atribuição de valor André?

Answer (score 1):

Em principio precisas só de

```
$nome = $_GET['nome'];
echo '<input class="input" type="text" name="nome" value="'.$nome.'"/>;'`
```

tendo em conta que deves sempre tratar conteudo que vem via `$_GET` antes de o usares.

Answer (score 0):

Estendo a resposta do membro Sergio, esta é a limpeza basica efetuada com valores provenientes de inserções do usuário, posteriormente você deverá passar os valores por cadeias de validação (usando `if` por exemplo).

```
$email = (trim(strip_tags($_GET['email'])));
echo '<input class="input" type="text" name="nome" value="'.$email.'"/>;'
```

> exemplo de validação mais fina.

```
if (array_key_exists("email", $_GET)) {
    //
}
```